# Fetch Data by connecting two tables : PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying t fetch the user_email based on the foreign Key I have set in the other table.

Suppose in one Table 'Users'I Have :

Users :
  id, user_email, user_phone etc.

and I Have other Table named patients as

patient_id, patient_name, doctor_id.

Where doctor_id is the foreign key to the Users Table.

I have the following code :

```
$query = "SELECT 'users.user_email' as 'name'
FROM users,patients 
WHERE 'users.id'='patients.doctor_id' AND 'users.id'='1';
" ;
 $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($conn,$query) ;

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['name'] ;
}
```

THe problem is its not working . its giving an error :

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\joli\data\foreigndata.php on line 10

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null 
given in C:\xampp\htdocs\joli\data\foreigndata.php on line 12
```

PS: The connection to the database is already established.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `mysqli_query()` to run the query and then `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` to get the result as used below:

```
$query = "SELECT users.user_email as name
FROM users,patients 
WHERE users.id=patients.doctor_id AND users.id=1;
" ;

$result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['name'] ;
}
```

Comment: @Abnit Chauhan The answer is updated let me know if your problem is not solved

Comment: it works now. thanks, I made a silly mistake. thanks for mentioning

Answer (score -1):

Try this

> select users.user_email as name from users inner join patients on
>   users.id=patients.doctor_id where users.id='1'

Answer (score -1):

**Try this**

```
$query = "SELECT 'users.user_email' as 'name' FROM users
inner join patients on 'users.id'='patients.doctor_id'
WHERE 'users.id'='1'";

$result = mysqli_query($query);

while ($row = myslqi_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['name'] ;
}
```

Comment: There are few mistakes in this answer. Single quotes cannot be used for column/table names. `myslqi_fetch_array` should be `mysqli_fetch_array`

Answer (score -1):

Like the error says, 
"**mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in**"

mysqli_fetch_assoc() only expects 1 parameter, but you're passing 2.

**Try this.**

```
$query = "SELECT 'users.user_email' as 'name'
FROM users,patients 
WHERE 'users.id'='patients.doctor_id' AND 'users.id'='1';
" ;

$result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['name'] ;
}
```

Comment: Single quotes cannot be used for column/table names.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
 $query = "SELECT 'users.user_email' as 'name' FROM users
    inner join patients on 'users.id'='patients.doctor_id'
    WHERE 'users.id'='1'";

    $result = mysqli_query($query);

    while ($row = myslqi_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row['name'] ;
    }
```

Comment: Single quotes cannot be used for column/table names.